# How To Create a Table in SQL in which the Column Names Follow Specific Pattern

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2012

I want to create a table called BREAK_EVEN in which the column names follow the pattern B_E0, B_E1, all the way to B_E(n) where n is the number of months that I have data for.

Is there a way in MS SQL Server 2012 to use a regular expression of some sort to add all of these columns in few lines of code?

Comment: This is generally a really bad design.   You should have a separate row for each value, rather than a separate column.

Comment: Are you looking to dynamically `create table` based upon some value `n`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I should have specified that n represents months, so I will have many rows of data for each value of n.

Comment: @sniperd Yes, I will use the number of columns from my revenue and cost tables as the number of columns for my breakeven table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this to do what you want:

```
DECLARE @THE_SQL VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @N INT = 5

SET @THE_SQL = 'CREATE TABLE BREAK_EVEN  ('

WHILE @N <> 0
    BEGIN
    SET @THE_SQL = @THE_SQL + ' [B_E' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @N) + '] INT,'
    SET @N = @N - 1
    END

SET @THE_SQL = @THE_SQL + ' ) ON [PRIMARY]'
PRINT @THE_SQL
```

You could also have it `EXECUTE` the SQL but I find in these cases it's a little safer to just have it print it out, and run it by hand.  It's going to loop 5 times (change that number to how many ever columns you want) and write out the `CREATE TABLE` statement to match.

Output in the `messages` tab:

```
CREATE TABLE BREAK_EVEN  ( [B_E5] INT, [B_E4] INT, [B_E3] INT, [B_E2] INT, [B_E1] INT, ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I had no idea that while loops were part of sql! lol, I just started sql yesterday, and loop weren't part of the intro course. If I had known, I wouldn't of asked this question!

Comment: No problem!  SQL has _some_ regular code you can do.  Look into `cursors` next.  However don't get too crazy writing actual code in SQL, it is very limited and performance is usually bad.  Use SQL for `CRUD` create, read, update and delete, try not to for business logic.  Put real logic in your app layer.  Good luck :)